# Different possible perimeters

Tags: geometry, contest-math, quadrilateral

> For some positive integers $p$, there is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with positive integer side lengths, perimeter $p$, right angles at $B$ and $C$, $AB=2$, and $CD=AD$.
>
> How many different values of $p$ are possible?

EDIT: $2015\geq{p}$

This is a contest problem by the AMC 12. As of right now, I am completely lost on how to solve it. I tried to rewrite everything as a single variable and then sieving through the integer values generated. Unfortunately, I could not consider the right angle.

I would appreciate IF HINTS ARE ONLY GIVEN AT FIRST. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image].

If $AD =CD= x$, then we have $BC= \sqrt{x^2-(2-x)^2} =2\sqrt{x-1}$. Thus, perimeter $$p = 2x +2\sqrt{x-1} +2$$ Now check what are the possible values $p$ can take.

Also, on a side note, is there any other condition specified?

Comment: Edited post to add new parameter.

Comment: I am sorry this is so late, but how did you derive the relationship between BC and y. I would really be grateful if you somehow depicted it.

Comment: Oh wait. I understand now. I forgot that there were two right angles, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $AC$ is the bisector of the angle at $A$. Call it $2\beta$.  Then
$$|AD|=|CD|=\frac{|AC|}{2\cos\beta}=\frac{|AC|}{2\frac{2}{|AC|}}=\frac{|AC|^2}{4}=\frac{4+|BC|^2}{4}=1+\frac{|BC|^2}{4}.$$
So the four sides have all positive integer lengths iff $|BC|=2k$ with $k$ a positive integer.

Therefore the perimeter is 
$$p=2+|BC|+|AD|+|CD|=4+|BC|+\frac{|BC|^2}{2}=4+2k+2k^2.$$

Is there any other hypothesis in your problem?